# Create Azure Synapse Pipeline using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-synapse

I'm new to Azure and was wondering if we can create Synapse pipeline using terraform. I tried searching on hasicorp website but could not find anything that specifically provided instructions on how to be able to create Azure Synapse pipeline using terraform.

Comment: its not possible as upto synapse workspace can be created using terraform , integration of pipeline and activity is only possible from synapse studio. please refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-pipelines

Answer (score 1):

> As of today, it is not possible to create Azure Synapse Pipeline using Terraform.

You can create Azure synapse pipeline using Azure CLI.

For more details, refer to [az synapse pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/pipeline?view=azure-cli-latest#az_synapse_pipeline_create)